# Sharepoint Email Trigger

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a Infopath form hosted in my company sharepont. In that there is a Submit Button. if I click the submit button it creating a document under the section "Metrics" in my Documents in Sharepoint. After saving the document Now I am getting an email that your metrics has been submited succesfully, copying my manager and other details.

Now my question is how can I set this to trigger an email when ever a document is created. It is basically a workflow. whoever creating an document it sends email to them.

Comment: What currently sends the e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the part where you said that an email already gets sent out upon saving the form, but why couldn't you just simply create a workflow that kicks off upon item creation (which means the form was submitted), and the only step you need in the workflow is to send an email to the Current Item's "Created By" person (using a lookup if you are working with SP Designer).